# how to set selection on image in contenteditable iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an contenteditable div and image with some Id within. How to set selection on this img using javascript?

[look on this link (its a picture)](http://test.standarta.net/test.jpg)

position 1: image BEFORE click,

position 2: image AFTER click.

What I need: I will click on some link and image with some id will become like position 2 in editable div. Link is out of conteneditable field

help me please

Comment: Hi Ilya, your question is very hard to understand. Please post the problem parts of your code, explain what you want to happen, and what is currently happening instead.

Comment: Ok, i'll try. myImg = window.document.getElementById(id); myRange = document.createRange(); myRange.selStart(myImg, .....); myRange.selEnd(myImg, .....); sel = document.getSelection(); sel.addRange(myImg); need to set selection on my img by id

Comment: Ilya, it's very hard to read that code, which even then is incomplete and doesn't show the HTML. Edit your question to present the code in a readable format (this [guide to markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will help format the code better), then explain, in two separate paragraphs 1) what is currently happening and 2) what you would want to happen. If the situation is quite complex, you can use a service like http://jsfiddle.net/ to implement the code and link to the saved example in your question.

Comment: Barny, look on this link (its a picture) http://test.standarta.net/test.jpg position 1: image BEFORE click, position 2: image AFTER click. What I need: I will click on some link and image with some id will become like position 2 in editable div. Link is out of conteneditable field.

Comment: I think I understand... But you should still _edit your question_ to show the information and the link. It will help others understand your problem and offer solutions!

Comment: How can I do it? I cant find 'edit message' (( May be just delete my message?

Comment: I've added the information as an edit, waiting for approval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean but with jQuery targeting the image would be something like this.

`$('#DivID #ImgID')`

or

`$('#DivID img')`

or just

`$('#ImgID')`

**EIDT--------------------------------------**

The below finds an image inside a div and references it with a variable `divImg`. Then the second line adds an ID to that img.

Something like that?

```
divImg = $('#DivID').find('img');
divImg.attr('id', 'imgNewID');
```

and if you want to set a click event to do it.

```
$('#IdClicked').on('click',function(){
   divImg = $('#DivID').find('img');
   divImg.attr('id', 'imgNewID');
});
```

Comment: No, need to set a selection on img with some id. For example I click a link, script found img in content editable div and set selection on this img. Create selection with addRange or something like this

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov ok... i think i get what you mean now please see my edit above.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your code change attribute of img. But I need to set selection on my img like I click on image in editable iframe - set focus on my image. I clicked on link - and img with id=my_id set focus. Sorry for my bad english (((

Comment: var s = window.getSelection()
   var r = document.createRange();
        r.selectNode(img);
        s.addRange(r);

Comment: sorry but I can't help you any further as I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Look here please: open link (its a picture) http://test.standarta.net/test.jpg. Position 1: image BEFORE click, position 2: image AFTER click. What I need: I will click on some link and image with some id within contenteditable div will become like image in position 2. Link is out of conteneditable field.

Comment: Right ok I see what you mean by focus now... please give me 2 mins to put together a jsfiddle.

Comment: There may be other ways around it but this was quick to put together

Comment: please look on my picture again: need to click NOT on target image, but on object (button, link etc) OUTSIDE contenteditable div. After click on button or link outside conteneditable div my img will take a focus. Thank you for your help...

Comment: then simply change the the click selector to something else...http://jsfiddle.net/KQYe2/3/ ....don't forget to mark the question as complete with the tick if it has helped.